# Strange behavior of upload files to server

Tags: php, html, forms, loops

I have strange behavior of upload files to server. I have no problem to get all files from 0 to 9. But it cannot get pass

```
no. 10 ($_FILES['video_file']['tmp_name'][**10**]).
```

It always returns: `Warning: Error: 8 (Can't open file or directory) in /home/...on line 89` Which 89 is the line of `$_FILES['video_file']['tmp_name'][$i]`.

I've checked the uploaded files on my server and database, I can get the **no. 10** video name `($_REQUEST['video_name'][**10**])`. But I just can't get the **No. 10** video file.

In php:

```
$count_for_loop = count($_FILES['video_file']); 
for($i=0; $i<$count_for_loop; $i++) {
  $_REQUEST['video_name'][$i];     
  $_FILES['video_file']['tmp_name'][$i];
}
```

In HTML:

```
<form name="upload" method="post" action="editing.php">
<input type="text" name="video_name[]" value="t1" />
<input type="text" name="video_name[]" value="t2" />
<input type="text" name="video_name[]" value="t3" />
<input type="text" name="video_name[]" value="t4" />
<input type="text" name="video_name[]" value="t5" />
<input type="text" name="video_name[]" value="t6" />
<input type="text" name="video_name[]" value="t7" />
<input type="text" name="video_name[]" value="t8" />
<input type="text" name="video_name[]" value="t9" />
<input type="text" name="video_name[]" value="t10" />
<input type="file" name="video_file[]" />
<input type="file" name="video_file[]" />
<input type="file" name="video_file[]" />
<input type="file" name="video_file[]" />
<input type="file" name="video_file[]" />
<input type="file" name="video_file[]" />
<input type="file" name="video_file[]" />
<input type="file" name="video_file[]" />
<input type="file" name="video_file[]" />
<input type="file" name="video_file[]" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I've google past few hours and search on SE, but it seems there is only happened to me in this world! Please help!

Comment: I don't see any HTML name `video_title`???

Comment: Oppsss...sorry, edited.

Comment: mmm You hav 10 inputs for type="file" it is 0 to 9. at least 10. how you are looking for 11th file?

Comment: @ Vadym Kovalenko Just tried your suggest to added 11 & 12, i can get video name 10, 11 & 12 but i can't get video files 10, 11 & 12. So weird! :S

Comment: Maybe its something to do with your php file size limit settings?

Comment: @ KyleK I just checked my phpinfo.: upload_max_filesize 4096M, post_max_size 1024M, max_file_uploads 1024. :S

Comment: I also tried to use parseint to adding (int)$count_for_loop & intval($count_for_loop) but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

For starters...

Shouldn't you be counting `$_FILES['video_file']` for the `$count_for_loop`..  Not `['video_title']`

Also...I would change this line....

```
for($i=0; $i<$count_for_loop; $i++) {
```

To this...

```
for($i=0; $i<=$count_for_loop; $i++) {
```

Comment: i can get video name no. 10, but it just can't get video file no. 10.